# Mover Floating Action Button, que esta sobre un Edittext Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un layout con varios edittext, el caso que el fab me está ocultando parte del edittext entonces al momento de escribir no deja ver lo que estoy escribiendo en el edittext, habrá alguna forma de moverlo justo cuando se llama al foco del edittext.

Necesitaria que se mostrara el edittext completo y si es posible rodar el fab hacia abajo Gracias.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pager"
    android:translationZ="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
    android:id="@+id/layoutinclude">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/material_gray_200"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
            android:id="@+id/layoutinclude4">
            <include layout="@layout/nombre"  android:id="@+id/name_one"/>
            <include layout="@layout/radiob"/>
            <include layout="@layout/nombre_em"  android:id="@+id/test3"/>
            <include layout="@layout/radio_inst_pub_priv" android:id="@+id/test1" />
            <include layout="@layout/e_persona_d" android:id="@+id/test2" />
            <include layout="@layout/e_persona_d_two" android:id="@+id/test4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/send" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Que tienes en tu MainActivity

Comment: @David nada fuera de lo normal. identifico los id y los paso a otra actividad

Answer (score 0):

Intenta sacar el Boton Flotante del CoordinatorLayout, para que asi este fuera del CardView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pager"
    android:translationZ="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
    android:id="@+id/layoutinclude">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/material_gray_200"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
            android:id="@+id/layoutinclude4">
            <include layout="@layout/nombre"  android:id="@+id/name_one"/>
            <include layout="@layout/radiob"/>
            <include layout="@layout/nombre_em"  android:id="@+id/test3"/>
            <include layout="@layout/radio_inst_pub_priv" android:id="@+id/test1" />
            <include layout="@layout/e_persona_d" android:id="@+id/test2" />
            <include layout="@layout/e_persona_d_two" android:id="@+id/test4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/send" />
```

Sino te funciona así entonces intenta colocarle un RelativeLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pager"
    android:translationZ="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
    android:id="@+id/layoutinclude">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/material_gray_200"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
            android:id="@+id/layoutinclude4">
            <include layout="@layout/nombre"  android:id="@+id/name_one"/>
            <include layout="@layout/radiob"/>
            <include layout="@layout/nombre_em"  android:id="@+id/test3"/>
            <include layout="@layout/radio_inst_pub_priv" android:id="@+id/test1" />
            <include layout="@layout/e_persona_d" android:id="@+id/test2" />
            <include layout="@layout/e_persona_d_two" android:id="@+id/test4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: esta fuera del cardview, con include llamo a los cardview con los edittexts- probare con el relativelayout

Comment: no funciona tu solicion

Comment: ok, esta bien pero puedes investigar un poco

Answer (score 0):

¿Que sucede en tu vista si colocas el **fab** entre el final del scroll y el final de LinearLayout ?

```
</ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Puede agregar los **include layout** pues los reemplace con **EditText** y no veo el mismo problema.